# Karma tests: Stop execution of all tests after the first spec failure

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have such a structure in a `.spec.ts` file:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {  
  describe('MyMethod', () => {
    //some testing stuff
  }
}
```

I wonder if there is a way (maybe some configuration to put into `client.jasmine` part of `karma.conf.ts`) to stop execution of **all** tests (not only a single suite). My goal is to run tests in vs code using `ng test` and if some error occurs, to see it right above the summary, so I wouldn't have to scroll up and look for it.

I've tried [failFast](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/Configuration.html) setting of `jasmine`, but this is not the right joice.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://github.com/michaelbull/karma-fail-fast-reporter

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the `failFast` of `jasmine` only does it for the `describe` block and not for all tests. You can try this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-fail-fast and you will need the `karma-jasmine` configuration.

Comment: @johey [fast-fail-reporter](https://github.com/michaelbull/karma-fail-fast-reporter) does not work for me as it does not support repeated running of tests. In my `karma` configuration I have `singleRun: false`, which causes to keep the tests running and when any test is changed, tests are run again. I noted an issue to the Github page, but it does not seem like the guy will respond soon (previous issue is from year 2017 and is without answer...). But maybe I'll be surprised :)

Comment: @AliF50 I tried to use the `karma-jasmine` configuration, but  `window.jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());` throws an error: `Error in config file!
 ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the library is maybe old and doesn't work any more. Sorry, I am not sure.